# Link button to application in Glade

Tags: python, gtk, glade

I'm new to Glade and I just love the possibilities this program has for (beginner) GUI developers. I started making an application with some text and buttons and I would like to assign a button to open `gnome-control-center`. How can I make a button in Glade open it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do it! After some research, I figured out the following would work:

**1. Import system processes**

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import subprocess
```

this need to be added at the top of AppNameWindow.py.

**2. Connect a button to an application**

```
def on_button1_clicked(self, widget, data=None):
       p = Process(target=self.launch_gcc)
       p.start()

def launch_gcc(self):
       subprocess.call(["gnome-control-center"])'
```

With this code you tell button1 to open GNOME Control Center when clicked. "gcc" in this example is a variable you can change yourself when adding another button.

**Adding URL to button**

You can also add an URL to a button with the following code:

**1. Import webbrowser**

```
import webbrowser
```

this need to be added at the top of AppNameWindow.py.

**2. Connect a button to an URL**

```
def on_button3_clicked(self, widget, data=None):
return webbrowser.open ('http://example.com')
```

With this code you tell button3 to open the webbrowser with "example.com" when clicked.